Does signature determine a finite variation path uniquely?
I am dealing with the signature of a finite variation curve $u: [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$, where the zeroth component is time, i.e. $u^0(t) = t$. Here the signature is the vector consisting of all iterated integrals up to time $T$, i.e. the vector has components
$$
\int_{0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n < T} du^{i_1}(t_1)\dots du^{i_n}(t_n),
$$
where $i_1, \dots, i_n \in \{0,\dots, d\}$.
Question: Knowing the components of the signature up to time $T$, i.e. all the integrals above for $i_1, \dots, i_n \in \{0,\dots, d\}$, is the path $u$ uniquely determined?
I am quite new to the topic of signature and although probably the answer can be found somewhere, I cannot seem to find it with my current understanding of the subject.
I think it is crucial that we include time as the zeroth component. So, is it true that uniqueness of the path fails, when we do not include $u^0(t) = t$?
I would be happy for every beginner friendly answer or reference. Maybe also a hint on how to show uniqueness for an easy example, say $u(t) = (t, \sin(t))$, would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Let $X,Y$ be two continuous $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$-valued paths of bounded variation such that the $0$th component is time, i.e. $X = (X^0,X^1,\dots,X^d)$ and $X^0_t=t$. Then, $S(X) = S(Y)$ if and only if $X_t = Y_t$ for every $t \in [0,T]$. More generally, the same holds under the assumption of continuous bounded variation paths in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ where at least one component is monotone (not necessarily time).
Intuitively, the signature fails to distinguish paths that retract back onto themselves. Hence, by assuming that at least one component of the path is monotone, we necessarily exclude the possibility of having such a retracting path.
For a reference and a proof you can check for instance Signature-based models: Theory and calibration, by Christa Cuchiero, Guido Gazzani, and Sara Svaluto-Ferro. Their statement is more general and it can be applied to your case.
